# How to post a message on wall of facebook using a graph api

Tags: facebook-graph-api

How to post a message on the wall of facebook or add comment to the thread using a graph api.I want a url of that.
like for adding a message to wall
https://graph.facebook.com/profile_id/feed?access_token=generated token&message=hi
But it not working ,it not get added to my wall.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `&method=post` to your request URL.  Also, you must have the [`publish_stream](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/) extended permission for your application.

Comment: Thank you.But I want to asked u that how to give publish_stream permission?If i trying to post on own wall,still it is saying that user is not authorised the application to  do this action.I don't have any app.

Answer (score 0):

https://graph.facebook.com/user_id/feed?method=post&message=hi&access_token=generatedtoken.. will work

instead of profile id give the user id

Hope this will work